# Unable to update image of containerApp with az up command

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry, azure-container-apps

I have a containerApp built with a default public image through a bicep script.
I assign a system managed identity to the containerApp. I have assigned AcrPull role to the identity on the ACR private registry[image]

The ACR private registry has admin credentials disabled, so I use managed identity in containerApp.

I try to update the containerApp with the image from ACR through azure shell using this command

```
az containerapp up -n mycontainerapp -g my-rg -i myregistry.azurecr.io/mybranch-dev:latest --ingress external --target-port 5173
```

[image]
getting this error:

```
Failed to retrieve credentials for container registry.  Please provide the registry username and password.
```

Can anyone help here ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have followed the below steps to establish connectivity between the ACR and ACA using managed identity to pull iimages as below. Please check if you could able to ressolve the issue by following the below steps.

To reproduce the issue, I have provisioned container app and container registry.
Go to Azure container apps and enable system assigned managed Identity as below and add AcrPull role.

[image]

[image]

[enter link description here](https://i.imgur.com/IsM4M0Y.png)

After adding the AcrPull role to the ACA, I pushed the sample image to the container registry as below.

[image]

Edit:

Now before updating the image in the container app from ACR, you have to edit revision as the existed revision is created with public repository.
To edit a  revision, go to containers in ACA and click edit and deploy.
[image]

[image]
Click on save and create a new revision. You can also use verify in [revisions](https://i.imgur.com/kxDeZgX.png).

Now I used `az containerapp update` to **update** the image

```
az containerapp update -n <container-app-name> -g <rg-name> -i acrvjyps.azurecr.io/nginx:v5
```

[image]

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/managed-identity-image-pull?tabs=azure-cli&pivots=azure-portal

Comment: thanks, i have already done these steps you had put, i am getting the errror as mentioned in my description, is your admin credentials enabled or disabled?